# Multiply polynomials under field $Z_3$

Tags: polynomials

As part of my journey in understanding finite fields , I have a little problem 
with multiplying polynomials .
Given: $(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ , a normal multiplication would be :

$(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ = $1 - 3 x^2 + x^4$

But this is incorrect since the correct answer (by the solution of my homework)  is : $x^4 +x^2 +1$

Can you please clarify how to compute the modulo here ?

Regards

Comment: $(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)=1 - 3 x^2 + x^4$ is right. In $\mathbb Z_3$, this is the same as $1+x^4$. Please check the question and the answer in the book. Perhaps it's in $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb F_4$, in which case your answer and the one given coincide.

Comment: Take for example the multiplication of : $(x^2 + 1) (x^4 + x^2 + 1)$ . A normal output is : $1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x^4 + x^6$ but the answer of the book is : $x^6 + x^4 + x^2 +1$ . So where is my mistake ?

Comment: Here, too, you're right and the book, if you're quoting it correctly, is wrong. Which book is this?

Comment: From a book of my professor , but maybe I'm the one to blame . The actual question is : calculate the multiplication of all irreduceable polynomials of power 2 , above $Z_3$ . So , I've tried with the following polynomials : $x^2+1  ,x^2+x-1 ,x^2-x-1$ , but the multiplication result of my calculation and the book (of the professor) are different . So , which it is :) ?

Comment: $(x^2+1)(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)=x^6-2 x^4-2 x^2+1=x^6+ x^4+x^2+1$.

Comment: or, mod 3, $(x^2+1)(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)=(x^2+1)(x^4+1)=x^6+x^4+x^2+1$.

Comment: You mean that : 1+2 = 0 (above $Z_3$) so $-2=1 , -1=2$ and so on ... but what about the coefficients ? if I have for exmaple $x^6$ above $Z_3$ , it stays $x^6$ ? no modulo with that ?

Comment: @ron: No. As as a *polynomial*, $x^6$ is just $x^6$; you don't do anything with the exponent. (Working over a finite ring/field, you have to be careful with the distinction between polynomials and polynomial functions, since different polynomials may define the same function). Powers of $x$ stay the same, you don't do anything with $x$ or with its exponents.